# I found an unknown ipv4 address on my router

Tags: router

I’m having issues with my sky router and my children’s access to inappropriate sites, I put blocked sites on my router and I’m now seeing an unidentfied ipv4 address trying to access the router for porn - the address is 100.103.216.0
All the other devices linked to my ip addresses are 192.168.0.1- 21
Can someone explain if I have a hacked computer on my system or whether it’s one of my kids mobile devices?
Many thanks

Answer (score 6):

Are you perhaps using [carrier-grade NAT (CGN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT)? That address you specified is part of [RFC 6598](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6598), a standard that specifies the address range 100.64.0.0/10 (which includes the address you provided). This means that it is not a local private address, but the address provided to you by your ISP. In order to overcome the [IPv4 shortage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_address_exhaustion), your ISP assigns you this special address, and then uses [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) to convert it to your real (shared) public IP address. In other words, the address you are seeing is the one between your router and your ISP, not between some device and your router. All this says is that *someone* is requesting a blocked domain through your router. Most likely culprits? Curious children.